# bonus on stereographic projections

Tags: complex-analysis

This is one of the bonus question that we are given. Its alright if you guys don't get it because I certainly don't. It will be nice if some one could tell me whats going on in this question. Or a solution to go with it so i learn off it. Thank you ver much guys/

What transformation of the complex plane lifts under stereographic projection to a rotation of the unit sphere by $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$ about the y axis? Find an isometry of the sphere which does not produce fractional linear transformation under stereographic projection.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

View the complex plane as the $xy$ plane $(x,y,0)$ and the sphere as being centered at $(0,0,0)$. Recall that all automorphisms (conformal isometries) of the Riemann sphere are given as fractional linear transformations when moved to the plane, so we are looking for some specific fractional linear transformation. Note this transformation interchanges $0$ and infinity (the projections of $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$), fixes $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,0)$ and interchanges $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$. This is more than enough information for you to solve for $a,b,c,d$ in $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ (the representation of a generic fractional linear transformation).

For the second part, we need to find a non-conformal isometry. Complex conjugation will do.

Comment: Usually, for stereographic projection, the unit sphere is centered at $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @arbautjc It can be done either way. Ahlfors does it the way I describe in his textbook. The exact same strategy works in either case.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know. Thanks!